# windowed OpenGL first frame delay after idle

Tags: winapi, opengl, freepascal

I have windowed WinApi/OpenGL app. Scene is drawn rarely (compared to games) in WM_PAINT, mostly triggered by user input - MW_MOUSEMOVE/clicks etc.

I noticed, that when there is no scene moving by user mouse (application "idle") and then some mouse action by user starts, the first frame is drawn with unpleasant delay - like 300 ms. Following frames are fast again.

I implemented 100 ms timer, which only does InvalidateRect, which is later followed by WM_PAINT/draw scene. This "fixed" the problem. But I don't like this solution.

I'd like know why is this happening and also some tips how to tackle it. 
Does OpenGL render context save resources, when not used? Or could this be caused by some system behaviour, like processor underclocking/energy saving etc? (Although I noticed that processor runs underclocked even when app under "load")

Comment: You should probably make this multi-threaded and separate GUI thread from the main application thread.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks for tip. But, you mean that separate GUI thread would draw scene in some high fps? I want my app to be as little power/resources hungry as possible. Or just existence of separate thread notifies Windows not to do unnecessary disk/virtual memory swapping?

Comment: No the GUI thread would merely smoothen graphics updates, by not getting stalled by things not related to the GUI. Whenever you try to patch up a single thread with stuff like WM_TIMER, the result tends to be quite ugly.

Comment: @Lundin: At the moment, there are no things unrelated to GUI. So I may implement separate thread later, if necessary. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in NVidia driver global 3d setting -"Power management mode".
Options "Optimal Power" and "Adaptive" save power and cause the problem.
Only "Prefer Maximum Performance" does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Windows virtual memory system at work. The sum of all the memory use of all active programs is usually greater than the amount of physical memory installed on your system. So windows swaps out idle processes to disc, according to whatever rules it follows, such as the relative priority of each process and the amount of time it is idle.

You are preventing the swap out (and delay) by artificially making the program active every 100ms.

If a swapped out process is reactivated, it takes a little time to retrieve the memory content from disc and restart the process.

Its unlikely that OpenGL is responsible for this delay.

You can improve the situation by starting your program with a higher priority.
https://superuser.com/questions/699651/start-process-in-high-priority

You can also use the `virtuallock` function to prevent Windows from swapping out part of the memory, but not advisable unless you REALLY know what you are doing!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT**: You can improve things for sure by adding more memory and for sure 4GB sounds low for a modern PC, especially if you Chrome with multiple tabs open.

If you want to be scientific before spending any hard earned cash :-), then open Performance Manager and look at Cache Faults/Sec. This will show the swap activity on your machine. (I have 16GB on my PC so this number is very low mostly). To make sure you learn, I would check Cache Faults/Sec before and after the memory upgrade - so you can quantify the difference!

Finally, there is nothing wrong with the solution you found already - to kick start the graphic app every 100ms or so.....

Comment: You're probably right. I checked also memory in task manager and at first sight it looked ok. 4GB RAM, 1GB used. But now I realized, that reading info about memory is not so straighforward and there still could be swapping. I changed my work machine. First was slow 3-core, 6GB RAM, GT710 with old drivers. There was no problem with app. New one is faster 4-core, 4GB RAM, same card with new drivers. So I was suspicios about drivers. Hopefully, I buy 4 more gigs tomorrow and confirm, if this was the problem.

Comment: @quantumfoam.  Before you by any extra memory - please read EDIT above. Also if you found my answer helpful, you may consider accepting the answer by clicking on the "tick' below the upvote/downvote arrows to the left of the answer :-). Doing this encourages responder's to help - but you are not obliged to accept.

Comment: Thanks for helpful tips, but the problem was in driver. Increase of process priority made no change. Cache faults were at 0.000, sometimes ticked to 0.986 or so. I did not buy memory yet, maybe later. :)

Comment: I had suspected power management earlier, but because of low memory I discounted. Too soon obviously. My PC even at 16GB goes to sleep also because of my settings. Saved some money and learned something new - great day!